# ERROR: Double requirement given: Pillow==6.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))

Tags: python, pip, odoo

I am using source code https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/aa0554d224337e1d966479a351a3ed059d297765

on Windows 10, Python version

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

I catch error

[image]

```
e:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxx\odoo>pip install -r requirements.txt
Ignoring gevent: markers 'sys_platform != "win32" and python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
Ignoring gevent: markers 'sys_platform != "win32" and python_version >= "3.7"' don't match your environment
Ignoring greenlet: markers 'python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
Ignoring lxml: markers 'sys_platform != "win32" and python_version < "3.7"' don't match your environment
Ignoring lxml: markers 'sys_platform != "win32" and python_version >= "3.7"' don't match your environment
ERROR: Double requirement given: Pillow==6.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25)) (already in Pillow==5.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24)), name='Pillow')

e:\source_code\github.com\xxxxxxx\odoo>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What is your `pip` version (check with `pip --version`)?

Comment: `pip 19.3.1 from c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: A straightforward fixing is remove the `Pillow==6.1.0` line in `requirement.txt`.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen Why? The OP is running Python 3.8 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in Odoo source code:

```
Pillow==5.4.1
Pillow==6.1.0 ; sys_platform == 'win32' and python_version >= '3.7'
```

This will clearly result in a double requirement if the condition in the second line is true.

I would suggest patching it as:

```
Pillow==5.4.1 ; sys_platform != 'win32' or python_version < '3.7'
Pillow==6.1.0 ; sys_platform == 'win32' and python_version >= '3.7'
```

which *should* work fine with all operating systems and Python versions.

Comment: Thank you! I am new with Odoo, I post issue at here https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/40080 although I am not sure it is a bug.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Odoo source either but I'm fairly certain that it's an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just get rid of line 24, and leave line 25, since it seems happy with that.

```
###Pillow==5.4.1
Pillow==6.1.0 ; sys_platform == 'win32' and python_version >= '3.7'
```

Edit: I changed my mind. If it likes both, it probably is better to go with the newer version...